# How to display multiple base64 encoded images in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a question... I can to display titles of all posts that received from database via `Iterable<PostModel> postsMain = postRepository.findAll();` (it also contains blob-images). But I can't understand correctly: For displaying of single image I getting byte code from DB and encoding it in base64 code, How do this with multiple images and display them like titles?

I displaying single image like this:

```
    Optional<PostModel> post = postRepository.findById(id);
    byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(post.get().getImage());
    String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
    modelAndView.addObject("contentImage", base64Encoded );
```

HTML-source: `<img class="post-image" th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${contentImage}}">`

I tryed to create `List` where I adding an base64 encoded string values.

My controller:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home ( Model model) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
    Iterable<PostModel> postsMain = postRepository.findAll();

    List<String> contentImages = new ArrayList<>();

    int size = Iterables.size(postsMain);

    for(int count = 0; count <= size; count++) {

        byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(postsMain.iterator().next().getImage());
        String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
        contentImages.add(base64Encoded);
    }

    modelAndView.addObject("contentImages", contentImages);
    modelAndView.addObject("posts_main", postsMain);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Good wishes.

Comment: Can you tell us where you are getting stuck? For example: Can you create your `List<String> contentImages` successfully? If not, can you show us how you tried? Your Thymeleaf looks OK - it just needs an iterator - for example: `<img class="post-image" th:each="contentImage : ${contentImages}" th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${contentImage}}">`.

Comment: I would recommend naming your Java list as `contentImages` (multiple images) not `contentImage`, just for clarity. And then, you need to use the Thymeleaf `th:each` iterator I mentioned in my first comment, which means: _"for each `contentImage` in the list of `contentImages`, display the image..."_.

Comment: I tryed do that via `while (postMain.iterator().hasText())`.  Inside this I created a byte array like this: `byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(postsMain.iterator().next().getImage());` , and after array I creating String with base64 code, then adding that all in `List<String>` which I initialized before this cycle

Comment: Okay, Thank you for good advices, I will know in future. I got "Java heap space" now (`th:each` already was used)

Comment: OK - understood. If you are already using `th:each` then you can [edit] your question to show that - and the other code you have added in your comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for help and your advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home ( Model model) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
    List<PostModel> postsMain = (List<PostModel>) postRepository.findAll();

    int size = Iterables.size(postsMain); //Receiving size of Iterator
    byte[] encodeBase64 = new byte[size];

    for(int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
        encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(postsMain.get(count).getImage());
        String base64Encoded = base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64, "UTF-8");
        postsMain.get(count).setMainPageImage(base64Encoded);
    }

    modelAndView.addObject("posts_main", postsMain);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

UPDATED: I added another, similar field in my `PostModel` (That also have getters ans setters) This field will not uploaded to DB:

```
private String mainPageImage;
```

Then I setting received `Base64` code via setter in `for` loop (above) like this:

```
postsMain.get(count).setMainPageImage(base64Encoded);
```

And finally, We're got this `HTML` section where displaying the picture and title from single collection:

```
<main>
  <div class="post-section">
     <div class="main-post" th:each="post : ${posts_main}">
         <div class="container">
             <img class="post-image" th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+${post.mainPageImage}}"/>
             <a href="/"><span th:text="${post.title}"></span></a>
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</main>
```